# remove non alphanumeric characters from fineuploader saved file

Tags: php, jquery, fine-uploader

Fineuploader is working well and I'm using the php-traditional-server-master. But I'd like to remove non alphanumeric characters from the filenames.  So "Bill's awesome video!.mp4" get saved as "Bills_awesome_video.mp4"
I see in the endpoint.php there is

```
// Specify the input name set in the javascript.
$uploader->inputName = "qqfile"; // matches Fine Uploader's default inputName value by default
```

but when I try to change this, the filename isn't affected.  I'm trying to change it by adding

```
params: {
   qqfile: "newfilename"
},
```

into the $('#fine-uploader-gallery').fineUploader

or this one that also didn't work

```
filenameParam: {
    qqfilename: "newfilename"
},
```

How can I specify a new name for the fineUploader to use?

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried to work with functions after requesting the parameter?

The [documentation](https://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/request-parameters.html) says: "Request parameters can be modified foremost by changing the values of the following options [...] Each function will be evaluated for each file that is submitted. The following code snippet demonstrates how one would track the current number of uploaded files."

```
    var fileNum = 0;

    // ...

        params: {
            fileNum: function () {
            return fileNum++;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea.  I think I'll have to use the Callbacks: onComplete to get the info so I can call my own nameChanger.php on the server side.